# Add custom payload to action cable's response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I want to add custom payloads to action cable's server response. I am native android app developer and experienced rails developer. The problem with action cable is it does set custom json response to message object.
If ping, server sends { `message: integer }` but if json sent, the response looks like this
`{ message: stringfied json }.` This may seems okay to JS developers but it's not easy to deserialize to POJO(Plain Java Object) with json serialization library. My Rails app is API. There is nothing wrong with the setup on both sides(Server Side and Android)

I have tried to deserialize both response. The app gets crash whenever i send json using `ActionCable.server.broadcast(channel, json`). message for ping is integer, but for json, it is object. You can not use one variable for 2 response type.
I can not use message for both integer and string in my android.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're going to have to show some code for us to be able to help. Please see [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)